# Bad Inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance

I'm doing an Android App and for some reason my inheritance is not working.

#### WITBase:

```
public class WITBase extends Activity {
    public static List <History> searches = new ArrayList<History>();
    public int index;
    public boolean newHistory(History history){
        searches.add(history); 
        index = history.index;
        
        System.out.println(index);  //Shows the right number    
        return true;
    }
```

and here's the problem:

#### WITInfo:

```
    public class WITInfo extends WITBase{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        System.out.println(super.index);//always shows 0 :/
        switch (super.index){
            case 2: case 3:
                setContentView(R.layout.mb_wit);
            case 4:case 5:case 6:
                setContentView(R.layout.bb_wit);
            case 7:
                setContentView(R.layout.it_wit);
            case 8:
                setContentView(R.layout.ftg_wit);
            case 1:case 9:
                setContentView(R.layout.tl_wit);
            default:
                setContentView(R.layout.info_wit);
        }
```

I don't know if this informations will be enough for you to help me, so if you need something more i'll write here.

Comment: No, it's not enough. You're not articulating a specific problem, you just say "here's the problem" and then post some code which doesn't seem problematic per se. Please tell us what you want to achieve, what do you expect the code to do and where exactly it does not do that.

Comment: Also "Bad Inheritance" is a Bad Title for a SO post, as it should ask a question or at least specify the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post in the stackoverflow and i did'nt know how to express here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value for your `WITBase.index` is 0. The `OnCreate` is the first thing that is called. So that explains the 0 value.

You should check the value at runtime when it has been set by `newHistory`.